# how to ignore order of values in a tuple with groupby - python

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[(999,777),(777,999),(777,999),(999,777),(299,331),(299,331),(543,829),(543,829),(829,543),(829,543),],'b':[44,32,42,15,65,36,92,57,77,42]})

df.groupby('a').aggregate('mean')

    a          b
(299, 331)    50.5
(543, 829)    74.5
(777, 999)    37.0
(829, 543)    59.5
(999, 777)    29.5
```

Instead of having different rows for tuples `(999,777)` and `(777,999)` for example, I'd like pandas to consider them as one. The output I'm looking for is

```
    a          b
(299, 331)    50.50
(543, 829)    67.00
(777, 999)    33.25
```

Comment: Would you be happy in pre-sorting 'a' first? `df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))
df.groupby('a').aggregate('mean')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a known sort order, aka sort the tuples:

```
In [6]: df.groupby(df['a'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))).aggregate('mean')
Out[6]: 
                b
a                
(299, 331)  50.50
(543, 829)  67.00
(777, 999)  33.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-sort:

```
In [45]:
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))
df.groupby('a').aggregate('mean')

Out[45]:
                b
a                
(299, 331)  50.50
(543, 829)  67.00
(777, 999)  33.25
```